# Writing sensor data to a text file- Arduino with Python

Tags: python-2.7, io, arduino

I am still learning to a beginner in exploring the power of Python programming along with Arduino and RPi.
Well I have written a short piece of code (getting help from different tutorials and posts), for writing the received sensor data from serial port along with the timestamp into a .txt file. Here is the code:

```
import serial, io
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *
from datetime import datetime

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com3',9600)
outfile = 'C:/Python27/test.txt'

sio=io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(arduinoData,arduinoData,1),encoding='ascii',newline='\r')

with open(outfile,'w') as f:
    while True: # while loop that loops forever
        while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0): #Wait here until there is data
            pass #do nothing
    arduinoString = sio.readline()
    f.write(datetime.now(),isoformat() + '\t' + arduinoString + '\n')
    f.flush()
    f.close()
```

- Kindly ignore the ***drawnow*** and ***matplotlib*** libraries as I would later use them to visualize the data.

The problem is that though the file is created in the said location, I am not getting anything written in the file. It could be possible that I am messing up completely. Therefore I need guidance on what is going wrong this program.

Your support is deeply appreciated! Thank you so much!

cheers

Pramit Sood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never getting out of your infinite `while True:` loop.

Indentation in Python is important.
You probably meant to do:

```
with open(outfile,'w') as f:
    while True: # while loop that loops forever
        while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0): #Wait here until there is data
            pass #do nothing
        arduinoString = sio.readline()
        f.write(datetime.now(),isoformat() + '\t' + arduinoString + '\n')
        f.flush()
```

Also don't close the file, if you want to keep writing to it.

Comment: Aaaah ok!!! Now I get it! Thank you so much gre_gor! It is writing to the file now! though quite small but for me a great learning!